# Difficulty in understanding linear regression with multiple features

Tags: python, linear-regression, data-analysis

Let's say price of houses(target variable) can be easily plotted against area of houses(predictor variables) and we can see the data plotted and draw a best fit line through the data.

However, consider if we have predictor variables as ( size, no.of bedrooms,locality,no.of floors ) etc. How am I gonna plot all these against the
target variable and visualize them on a 2-D figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation shouldn't be an issue (the math works regardless of dimensionality), but the plotting definitely gets tricky. PCA can be hard to interpret and forcing orthogonality might not be appropriate here. I'd check out some of the advice provided here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73320/how-to-visualize-a-fitted-multiple-regression-model

Fundamentally, it depends on what you are trying to communicate. Goodness of fit? Maybe throw together multiple plots of residuals.

Comment: With respect to your concern about residual distributions, I wouldn't eyeball it. Try qualifying it  with an appropriate metric. See: http://www.okstate.edu/sas/v8/sashtml/ets/chap14/sect39.htm

Comment: That link really helped me understand some good stuff!! Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want a 2D figure, that's certainly not easy. One possible approach would be to reduce the dimensionality of your data to 2 using something like [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). Then you can plot it in two dimensions again. Reducing to 3 dimensions instead of 2 might also still work, humans can understand 3D plots drawn on a 2D screen fairly well.

You don't normally need to do linear regression by hand though, so you don't need a 2D drawing of your data either. You can just let your computer compute the linear regression, and that works perfectly fine with way more than 2 or 3 dimensions.

Comment: That helped!!Thanks Dennis.

Comment: But had just one more confusion that if residual plots are to be visualized w.r.t to predictor variables(5 or 6 let's say) then to check Heteroskedasticity I will have to bring them to 2D howsoever. What happens in that case then?